# Image sprite from backgound-image url without preprocessors, mixins, watchers an so on

Tags: html, css, svg, gulp, sprite

I want to concat icons in my project into one single sprite image. I found a few solutions but all of them require to use css preprocess mixins or something in my original CSS code. What I want is to use as less technologies and libraries as possible.

I have two folders in my project:

```
resources/
public/
```

Both of them have the same structure:

```
images/
layouts/
scripts/
styles/
...
```

I work in **resources/** folder. I write HTML, CSS, JS normally. I store images there as I cut them from Photoshop/Sketch. I open HTML file from this folder in browsers and everything is fine. All resources is not compress and not optimized. I don't use any preprocessors or watcher.

When I finish work or part of it I run **GULP** with some plugins. It copy all resources into **public/** folder and compress, concat, optimize them. And I want to create image sprite during this step.

So in my original **resources/** folder I want my CSS looks like so:

```
.facebook-icon {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-image: url(../images/facebook-icon.svg);
}
.bubble-peak {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-image: url(../images/bubble-peak.png);
}
```

It will let me work normally. I can see images on the page without compilation. Just code and refresh page in the browser.

When I finish work I want to see my public CSS like so:

```
.facebook-icon {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-image: url(../images/sprite.svg);
    background-position: -100px -500px;
}
.bubble-peak {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-image: url(../images/sprite.png);
    background-position: -500px -100px;
}
```

Is that possible with any libraries or GULP-plugins?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**postCSS** plugin called **postcss-sprites** do the trick:
https://github.com/2createStudio/postcss-sprites

But it doesn't work with vector graphics.

Comment: Later I decide to deal with vector graphic another way, so this one does the perfect job with raster sprites.